# If $G$ is abelian and if $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ prove that $G/N$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There's a problem in Herstein which goes as:

> If $G$ is abelian and if $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ prove that $G/N$ is abelian.

I think there's a typo for there's no mention that $N$ is normal in $G$ or is there a interpretation for $G/N$ when $N\leq G$ is arbitrary?

Comment: Think about the definition of normality; could $N$ be otherwise in this case?

Comment: Which book of Herstein?

Answer (score 3):

A subgroup is normal if the left and right cosets coincide. That is if $x + N = \{x+ a \; | \; a\in N \} = N +x = \{a + x \; | \; a \in N \}$. In the case of abelian groups this is obviously true so all subgroups of an abelian group are normal. Now take any two elements in $G/N$ say $x + N $ and $y + N$ then we must show that $ (x + N) + (y + N) = (x+y) + N$ is the same as $(y+N) + (x+N) = (y +x ) + N$. I leave this as an exercise (hint G is abelian).

Answer (score 1):

Another similar hint may be:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of it so, $$G/N~~\text{is abelian}\Longleftrightarrow G'\le N$$

Comment: Hello, dear friend! +1, but you might want to make explicit what $G'$ denotes. ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Hi Amy, $G'$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$. Not good day. You can find it easily. :-)

Comment: @amWhy: Indeed, I hink about that answers I made for that removed user. Are they lost? Since, I don't know who was it and what was my answers now. :-)